# get deleted contacts from ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, android-contacts

This query returns deleted contacts some time. I have noticed if the deleted contacts belong to Gmail account and have numbers then this query will not return any result.

```
String WHERE_DELETED = "( " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.DELETED + "=1)";

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                WHERE_DELETED,
                null,
                null);
```

Comment: Can we get deleted contacts with last modified timestamp in the query ?

Answer (score 1):

The `RawContact.DELETED` **marks** the `RawContact` for deletion, once the relevant `SyncAdapter` wakes up and syncs the deletion to the server (e.g. Google Contacts Server) that `RawContact` is actually deleted from the DB and **can no longer be queried**.

See [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#DELETED):

> The "deleted" flag: "0" by default, "1" if the row has been marked for
>   deletion. When delete(Uri, String, String[]) is called on a raw
>   contact, it is marked for deletion and removed from its aggregate
>   contact. The sync adaptor deletes the raw contact on the server and
>   then calls ContactResolver.delete once more, this time passing the
>   CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER query parameter to finalize the data removal.

What you can do is query the `ContactsContract.DeletedContacts` table which holds a record of Contacts deleted in the last 30 days, see here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.html